# Object of class App\Billing\FakePaymentGateway could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, object, payment-gateway

There was 1 error:

1) ViewConcertListingTest::customer_can_purchase_concert_tickets
ErrorException: Object of class App\Billing\FakePaymentGateway could not be converted to string

Doing test, and can't figure out what's it's complaining about...

```
<?php

namespace App\Billing;

class FakePaymentGateway implements PaymentGateway
{

    private $charges;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->charges = collect();
    }


    public function getValidTestToken()
    {
        return "valid-token";
    }



    public function charge($amount, $token)
    {
        $this->charges[] = $amount;
    }

    public function totalCharges()
    {
        return $this->charges->sum();
    }

}
```

Heres the other part of it
PurchaseTiketTest.php

```
<?php
    class ViewConcertListingTest extends TestCase
    {
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    /**
    * @test
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function customer_can_purchase_concert_tickets()
    {
    $paymentGateway = new FakePaymentGateway;

    $this->app->instance(PaymentGateway::class, $paymentGateway);
    //dd($paymentGateway);

    // Arrange

    //Create a concert
    $concert = factory(Concert::class)->create(['ticket_price' => 3250 ]);


    // Act

    // View the concert listing

    $response = $this->json('POST', "/concerts/{$concert->id}/orders", [
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'ticket_quantity' => 3,
    'payment_token' => $paymentGateway->getValidTestToken(),
    ] );

    $response->assertStatus(201);


    $this->assertEquals( 9750 , $paymentGateway->totalCharges() );

    $order = $concert->orders()->where('email')->first();

    $this->$this->assertNotNull($order);

    $this->assertEquals( 3, $order->tickets->count() );
    }


    }
```

Order Controller with comment on line 18

```
class ConcertsOrdersController extends Controller
{

    private $paymentGateway;

    public function __construct(PaymentGateway $paymentGateway)
    {
        $this->$paymentGateway = $paymentGateway; // Line 18
    }

    //
    public function store($concertId)
    {
        $concert = Concert::find($concertId);

        $ticketQuantity = request('ticket_quantity');

        $amount = $ticketQuantity * $concert->ticket_price;

        $token = request('payment_token');

        $this->paymentGateway->charge($amount, $token);


$concert->orders()->create(['email' => request('email')]);


        return response()->json([], 201);
    }
}
```

Expected to be Passed Results

Comment: 1. Where is your test file. 2. Post the FULL error message. It contains the line where the error occurred, it's not a random number, it means something.

Comment: https://ibb.co/n3yLZQg

Comment: See that the first line of your error stack trace points to your controller? Post your controller (and please point us the line 18)

Comment: Appreciate your time, as I'm confused , the tutorial videos on this seem to be older, and nothing goes according as to what it looks on them...

Comment: ```
interface PaymentGateway 
{
    public function charge($amount, $token);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is a simple additional (unwanted) `$` before your property name on line 18 of `ConcertsOrdersController`:

```
    $this->$paymentGateway = $paymentGateway; // Line 18
```

When you do this, you tell to PHP to get the value of `$paymentGateway` as string, and set a method called with that string value.

For example:

```
$paymentGateway = 'test';
$this->$paymentGateway = 123;
echo $this->$paymentGateway; // 123
echo $this->test; // 123
```

The error occurs because your `$paymentGateway` variable is a object instead of a string.

Actually, you added a extra `$` on your line 18. It should look like this:

```
    $this->paymentGateway = $paymentGateway; // Line 18
```

Comment: Your a star ,  I was too annoyed , and couldn't notice 
Thanks a lot